# Does activity on stack exchange increase during the Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, statistics, winter-bash

Hopefully this is the right place to ask:

Does activity on stack exchange increase during the Winter Bash?

I'm guessing this possible using http://data.stackexchange.com, but I couldn't find any existing query across all sites that would do it.  I'd think the mother-ship would know the answer.

"Activity" is open to interpretation, but I was thinking of any of the following:

- # of site visits (breakdown by return vs. new to normalize)
- # of questions asked
- # of questions answered
- # of questions edits
- # of votes (breakdown by up and down might be interesting)
- # of comments

Comment: site visits is not in SEDE, maybe in the 25K site-analytics tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging from the site analytics, definitely yes *here on Meta.SE* and *for the first few days*, but other sites are not so clear.

Following are the graphs from Meta.SE for Nov 1 through Jan 31 in each of the last three Winterbashes, plus 2011 for comparison.  (Winterbash began in 2012.)

2014:

[image: 2014 graphs]

Traffic stats aren't available for earlier years (or at least weren't when I looked), so the rest of these will show only posts and votes.

There are two bumps in 2013.  I couldn't find the exact start date for Winterbash that year:

[image: 2013 graphs]

And 2012, the first Winterbash:

[image: 2012 graphs]

What did activity look like before Winterbash?  Here's 2011:

[image: 2011 graphs]

I chose Meta.SE because, anecdotally, this site seems to be the largest attractor of Winterbash activity -- if it didn't show up *here* it probably wouldn't *elsewhere*.  So I checked another active site where I have access to analytics, The Workplace, and found a very different pattern.  Here's last year's report:

[image: Workplace 2014 graphs]

The effect on Mi Yodeya is similar.  The other sites where I have access to site analytics are smaller and might not be good indicators.