# Is there a way to propose badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Badges are great, as well as achievements - they encourage people and make discussion, asking question and answering more fun. There are standard badges, which are cool, but from time to time I'm thinking: "Ouch, would be could if there would be an achievement for this...".
Is there a way for community to propose new badges? What I can think of are:

- Answering in less than 1 minute and getting your answer accepted
- Getting reputation to some specific number: prime number, 1337, 31415
- Answering more than, say, 30 questions a day for the question with the same tag

Answer (score 4):

You propose badges by doing what you just did... making a post here on MSE...

Now, you're going to need to do more than just explain the badge.

You'll need to come up with a name/names, note which level of badge it would be, explain the benefits of this badge - badges must always encourage positive behaviors - and consider any downsides.

Some examples:

[New Badge Proposal: Renaissance Man](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92138/new-badge-proposal-renaissance-man)
[New badge proposal based on number of profile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6578/new-badge-proposal-based-on-number-of-profile-views)
[Badge suggestion: Unsung Hero (5 accepted answers with no votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/badge-suggestion-unsung-hero-5-accepted-answers-with-no-votes)

Please note the usage of the [badge-request](/questions/tagged/badge-request) tag. Feel free to look at [these other highly voted badge requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badge-request?sort=votes&pageSize=50) for reference.

Comment: Worth mentioning that some badges get a trial run during [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272248/158100).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Post a question here on Meta.SE. Please tag it with [badge-request](/questions/tagged/badge-request).

Comment: I promise, I googled before ask :) Thank you, @Mithrandir!